# Jquery detect radio group then validate

Tags: jquery, validation, foreach, radio-button

I've searched forums, google, and stack - no avail.

Basically, a client is generating radio buttons on our page, and we need to validate them. Each Radio group uses the same name (i.e TM_Offer_0056) and there will be a YES, and NO option for each name.

How can i group through each NAME and just make sure either one is checked.

I am able to detect all radio buttons, but an unable to group them and validate them.

```
  $(":radio").each(function() {   
  var radioName = this.name;

  if ($('input[name='+ radioName +']:checked').length) {
      //button was checked
  }
  else {
       // no radio button was checked
        strErrorMsg +="Please Select an Option for "+this.name+"\n";
  }//end check


  });

if (strErrorMsg==""){
//validation passed, do something
}else{
alert(strErrorMsg);
return false;
}
```

That code alerts at the end that each button is not checked. I only need ONE of the radios checked per group name. Each set will have a different name, so i just need to detect all the names of checkboxes, group them into 2's, and make sure 1 of them is checked.

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you first get all the unique check box names first and store them in a array or json and then for each name try to see if the radio button is checked ?

Comment: i'm not 100% on how to achieve that. Any sample code would be highly appreciated. Just like push each name into an array (since 2 have same name, it'll push into SAME array?) then check each array for atleast one checked? Would love some exmaple code to kinda visualize what I need to do. Thanks again.